# Invision Power Board: Add message at top of board index

Tags: ipb

And here I am, wasting my time trying to achieve things that would take two minutes with any other forum software.
IPB's template system is **insane**.

Anyway: I just want to add a simple block of HTML, specifically a paragraph of text, on top of my board's index page, before the forums list. Could someone be so kind to point me in the right direction? i.e., what's the template I have to edit?

Thanks a lot, any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out how to do it:

1. ACP, Look & Feel, IP.Board, Templates, Board Index, `boardIndexTemplate`.
2. Find `<!-- CATS AND FORUMS -->`
3. Add after it:

   ```
   <div class="message" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
   Your message here
   </div>
   ```

Plus if you want to show the message for guests only, wrap that HTML code in this if statement:

```
<if test="!$this->member->getProperty('member_id')">

</if>
```